# How to dynamically update date and time in flex from the server?

Tags: apache-flex, servlets

I have a GUI in flex. I am getting the value of the server date from the servlet to the .mxml file. I want to show the date and time dynamically changing. How can I do that in flex?

Comment: Date/time is retrieved only once (in the startup), right? In that case update the time display control when the server response arrives. It is hard to say without seeing details. (How is the time fetched - `HTTPService` or `URLLoader` or ...?)

Comment: the time is fetched by HTTPService

Answer (score 0):

You would have to keep repolling the server or use push technologies and push the date to Flex.